# Changing the Eclipse toolbar - Removing the Launch Bar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, toolbar

I installed Eclipse a while ago, and for some reason I never worked out - for this installation, the main toolbar appeared as shown below!

[image]

I left it for a while, thinking it the new 'thing' for Mars, but after seeing a friends Mars installation without this, want the old 'regular' launch toolbar back - but unsure on how to do this!

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is something to do with pydev - do you have that installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found out what it is ...the "launch bar" included in new and noteworthy for Mars. And is described as [image]

Which is how to get rid of it!

Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

try playing with to options in Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective....

theoretically you can customize your toolbar however you want

Comment: But is there no way of just...completely replacing this toolbar? Or would that require a fresh install of eclipse?

Comment: you can try to change the theme if it's possible: windows -> preferences ->  general -> preferences -> appearance -> select classic in the theme dropdown

I don't know it that will work, but you can give it a try. If you can't find it, just type in the search box theme, under the windows -> preferences